# Topics as tags in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have several long-lived domains (~one week) that can be accessed using STOMP topics, eg an endpoint `/domain/:domainId`. Currently I am monitoring them as messages with `uri` tag but am considering adding the `domainId` also.

`stomp_endpoint{uri='/domain/:domainId'}`

into

`stomp_endpoint{uri='/domain/:domainId', domainId='<UID>'}`

There is business value that can be gained by doing this but I am not sure about the cost such tagging would add to our monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Prometheus [relabelling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config). Just add a replace action to your Prometheus job. The source would be the `uri` label, the target `domainId` and the regex a pattern to get the domainId in a capture group. The replacement parameter is by default `$1` (the first capture group), I've added it just to clarify the action:

```
    - source_labels: [uri]
      action: replace
      target_label: domainId
      regex: /domain/(.+)
      replacement: $1
```

Comment: Actually I have complete control over the tags in the monitored service. I can add it if needed. The question is if I should do it, if this is something that is generally done.

Comment: Yes, relabelling is a powerful tool to improve queries. You can monitor prometheus itself and watch processing time metrics, but I am pretty sure it is a cheap operation.